# Select a value ending in letters from a list of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a column which has a data type of `varchar(25)`, while the values in the column could be something like `'89009', 'HS123','4491AU', '44989EA'`.

How do I select values of which the **LAST TWO** digits are not numbers but letters?

In this case how do I select only '**4491AU**' and '**44989EA**'

Please advise.

Thank you all. Problem solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `like`:

```
where col like '%[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]'
```

or, if you just want non-digits:

```
where col like '%[^0-9][^0-9]'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from your_table
where some_column like '%[A-Z][A-Z]'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?
http://rextester.com/ZEO59984

```
SELECT *
    ,isnumeric(right(value, 2)) AS IsNumericCheck
FROM table1
    where isnumeric(right(value,2)) = 0
```

The Isnumeric function checks whether the input is numeric. Returns 1 if it is numeric and 0 if it is not. 
In the code above, the are using the right 2 characters of the Value column to perform the check.

Comment: This only kind of works. IsNumeric returns a LOT of false positives. Here are a few 2 characters strings that will evaluate to true with IsNumeric. .8, $4, 2. I am pretty sure the OP wants where the last two characters are numbers.

Comment: Learn something new everyday! Dmitriy said the same thing, but I am reading the OP's question as "not numbers". Either way, the regex answers are also good

Comment: Oh and one of my favorites that evaluates to true "$.". No clue how a dollar sign and a period (decimal point) alone can be numeric. But it is because you can convert it to money. select convert(money, '$.') Bizarre huh??